# Return records for current and previous year with year passed in a WHERE clause for Acumatica report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, acumatica

Suppose I have a SQL view called INForecastTotalSales.
This view contains the following columns:

InventoryID, FinYear, TotalSales

I would like to create another view INForecastTotalSalePrevCurr, which would have the following columns:

InventoryID, FinYear, CurrentYearTotalSales, PreviousYearTotalSales

so that when I query
`SELECT * FROM INForecastTotalSalePrevCurr i WHERE i.FinYear = 2020`
the view would populate CurrentYearTotalSales, PreviousYearTotalSales with TotalSales data for 2020 and 2019 respectively. The catch if we have to join the original view on itself, it would have to be FULL OUTER JOIN, since we need data from both tables for all inventory id's.

I have tried using OUTER APPLY and putting the same view into a table valued function, but this would essentially work as LEFT JOIN.

The view would have to be used in Acumatica Report, so can't really pass parameters, if I were to use a function or stored procedure. I am limited to using WHERE clause, unless someone has some other suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]- word descriptions fail to communicate the complexity of these problems.

Comment: Probably better to start off with the inventory table, left join the two forecasts onto that, or left join it once and use `LAG()` to get the previous year. Can't say without seeing the query and tables

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 2 views?

Better approach would be to create a single view with columns:

`InventoryID, FinYear, CurrentYearTotalSales, PreviousYearTotalSales, TotalSales`

Where I think you are going wrong is the assumption that you have to use `SELCT * FROM ...`.  In fact this a poor approach and it is bettwe to explicitly state the columns as in:

`SELECT InventoryID, FinYear, TotalSales FROM INForecastTotalSales`
or
`SELECT InventoryID, FinYear, CurrentYearTotalSales, PreviousYearTotalSales FROM INForecastTotalSales`

That will likely simplify your view creation and also make your queries more robust.